# `anchor test` error: Failed to run test: yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts: No such file or directory (os error 2)

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, anchor, smartcontracts, solana

I just initialized a solana dapp with `anchor init`. Then I built successfully with `anchor build`. I tried to test `anchor test` command too but it fails and I have not added any code yet. This is still untouched initialized code and this is the error message:

```
Failed to run test: yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

It says there is not file inside `tests` directory but there is `mydapp.ts` with this code

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Mydapp } from "../target/types/mycalculatordapp";

describe("mydapp", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.Provider.env());

  const program = anchor.workspace.Mydapp as Program<Mydapp>;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    // Add your test here.
    const tx = await program.rpc.initialize({});
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install yarn globally since I did not have it on my system

```
 sudo  npm i -g yarn
```

Then I got `ts-mocha` command not found even though it was on `package.json`. so I run `npm install` to install all dependencies. Then I got `ts node` error

```
  sudo npm i -g ts-node
```

Finally it works